# how not loading javascript code in lt IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

i use javascript code in project and i want not load this code in lt IE 9. i use this code but its not working:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript">
....
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!--[if !lt IE 9]>-->
...
<!--<![endif]-->
```

You can visit this [microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.ASPX) to learn how to build more complex conditional comments

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>-->
...
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Target IE 8 and lower -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript">alert('hello world');</script>
<![endif]-->
```

So perhaps give this a try:

```
<!-- Target IE 9 and lower -->
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
    <script type="text/javascript">alert('hello world');</script>
<![endif]-->
```